# Using entropy to imputing missing value based on grey relational analysis and clustering

Tags: clustering, data-mining, missing-data, entropy, multiple-imputation

**This algorithm contain three techniques :**

**1-fuzzy c-mean clustering**
[image]
**2-Grey relational theory**
[image]
**3-Entropy multiple imputation**
[image]
[image]

**The frame work of this algorithm is as follows :**
[image]
[image]

**My questions are about the entropy technique :**

1- what is rfl and ril stand for from equation(5) or how to calculate hf from
step(1) .

2- (L not equal to j ) what that mean and what is L in equation (5).

3- How to calculate pf from (If= -k *hf *lnpf)

4- How to determine equation(8) or step(4)

**If someone have information about this algorithm  can you help me by some advices or give me any related work like this  algorithm  .

***please some one help me***

full article (http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2013/720392/)